# Получить отправителя сообщения, получателя и сам текст

Tags: mysql, sql

Проблема такая: не получается получить получателя сообщения, выводит одно и тоже имя, как сделать, что бы выводило всё правильно? А вообще так делают или всё по другому?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/269bf0/1

```
SELECT users.name AS sender, users.name AS recipient, message.text FROM users
    LEFT JOIN message ON message.author_id = users.id
```

---

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.3.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1
-- Время создания: Дек 27 2017 г., 21:36
-- Версия сервера: 5.6.24
-- Версия PHP: 5.6.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `lesson14`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `message`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `message`
--

INSERT INTO `message` (`id`, `user_id`, `author_id`, `text`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 2, 1, 'Здарова, пошли кататься на сноутах? ', 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Дима'),
(2, 'Андрей');

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `message`
--
ALTER TABLE `message`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `message`
--
ALTER TABLE `message`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: "не получается получить получателя" - это не беда. Хуже, когда не удается сообщить сообщение сообщения. Или повременить со временем времени.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы разыменовать два внешних ключа нужно два join'а.

```
SELECT sender.name, recipient.name, message.text FROM message
    LEFT JOIN users AS sender ON message.author_id = sender.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS recipient ON message.user_id = recipient.id
```

---

ЗЫ: Кстати их стоило бы объявить таковыми...

Comment: не понимаю, почему так работает sender.name, обычно я всегда делал так только с таблицами, которые реально есть, то есть users.name

Comment: JOIN users **AS sender**: «sender» это просто ещё одно имя для таблицы users в контексте данного JOIN'а. Не особо пойму что тут может смущать...

Comment: про AS я знаю, не понимаю sender.name, обычно первое это название таблицы, а второе строка, а такой таблицы нету

Comment: Не знаю уже как объяснить =)... просто так это устроен механизм именования. В синтаксисе SELECT вместо имени таблицы можно использовать её псевдоним. А в некоторых случаях без оного не обойтись, как например сейчас, когда одна и та же таблица встречается в двух JOIN'ах, или когда вместо таблицы стоит подзапрос, или когда ну очень хочется сэкономить немножечко места, чтобы запрос нормально читался, а не растягивался на 3 страницы.